# Android eclipse nullpointexceptionerror at runtime

Tags: android, eclipse

I keep getting a Nullpointexceptionerror at runtime. According to logcat the error is caused by line 43 which is:

```
Database databaseNieuw = new Database(new File(naamDatabase), Version.DBASE_4);
```

The only thing in that line which could throw such an error would be naamDatabase which is a String aquired from an EditText field. Which are both defined above line 43.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Logcat:

```
01-15 23:44:40.292: E/Trace(20437): error opening trace file: No such file or directory     (2)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib.Database.<init>(Database.java:112)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib.Database.<init>(Database.java:64)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at com.example.bosbouwapp.screen1$2.onClick(screen1.java:43)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4102)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17085)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
01-15 23:44:46.769: E/AndroidRuntime(20437):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code:

```
package com.example.bosbouwapp;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib.Database;
import nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib.Field;
import nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib.InvalidFieldLengthException;
import nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib.InvalidFieldTypeException;
import nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib.Type;
import nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib.Version;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class screen1 extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen1);

    Button terug = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);    
    terug.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), home.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }

    });

    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
     next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View view) {

                EditText databaseNaam = (EditText)    findViewById(R.id.database_naam);
                String naamDatabase = databaseNaam.getText().toString();
                Database databaseNieuw = new Database(new File(naamDatabase), Version.DBASE_4);            
                Global g = (Global) getApplication();
                List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
                List<Field> fields2 = new ArrayList<Field>();

      if (naamDatabase.trim().equals("")) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Veld is leeg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }  
      else{

    fields.add(new Field("Stapel", Type.NUMBER, 3));
    fields.add(new Field("Boomsoort", Type.CHARACTER, 25));
    fields.add(new Field("Diameter", Type.NUMBER, 4));
    fields.add(new Field("Lengte", Type.NUMBER, 2));
    fields.add(new Field("Overig", Type.CHARACTER, 150));
    try {
        databaseNieuw.addTable("Boomstam", fields);
    } catch (InvalidFieldTypeException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFieldLengthException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    fields2.add(new Field("Stapel", Type.CHARACTER, 50));
    fields2.add(new Field("Datum", Type.DATE));
    fields2.add(new Field("X", Type.NUMBER, 20));
    fields2.add(new Field("Y", Type.NUMBER, 20));
    fields2.add(new Field("Houtsoort", Type.CHARACTER, 50));


    try {
        databaseNieuw.addTable("Houtstapel", fields2);
    } catch (InvalidFieldTypeException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidFieldLengthException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    g.setDatabaseNieuw(databaseNieuw);      
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), screen3.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


        }

    }


    });
}
}
```

EDIT

I'm currently looking into the Database.class. As I can't really make heads or tails out of it (yet), maybe someone else can.

Code of Database.class:

```
// Decompiled by DJ v3.12.12.96 Copyright 2011 Atanas Neshkov  Date: 1/16/2013 12:48:01 AM
// Home Page: http://members.fortunecity.com/neshkov/dj.html  http://www.neshkov.com/dj.html - Check often for new version!
// Decompiler options: packimports(3) 
// Source File Name:   Database.java

package nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.*;

// Referenced classes of package nl.knaw.dans.common.dbflib:
//            Table, Version, InvalidFieldTypeException, InvalidFieldLengthException

public class Database
{

public Database(File databaseDirectory, Version version)
{
    this(databaseDirectory, version, Charset.defaultCharset().name());
}

public Database(File databaseDirectory, Version version, String charsetName)
{
    tableMap = new HashMap();
    if(databaseDirectory == null || databaseDirectory.isFile())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Database must be a directory ");
    if(!databaseDirectory.exists())
        databaseDirectory.mkdirs();
    this.databaseDirectory = databaseDirectory;
    this.version = version;
    this.charsetName = charsetName != null ? charsetName : Charset.defaultCharset().name();
    Charset.forName(this.charsetName);
    String fileNames[] = databaseDirectory.list();
    String arr$[] = fileNames;
    int len$ = arr$.length;
    for(int i$ = 0; i$ < len$; i$++)
    {
        String fileName = arr$[i$];
        if(fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(".dbf") && fileName.length() > ".dbf".length())
            addTable(fileName);
    }

}

public Set getTableNames()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(tableMap.keySet());
}

public Table getTable(String name)
{
    return (Table)tableMap.get(name);
}

public Table addTable(String name, List fields)
    throws InvalidFieldTypeException, InvalidFieldLengthException
{
    Table table = (Table)tableMap.get(name);
    if(table == null)
    {
        table = new Table(new File(databaseDirectory, name), version, fields);
        tableMap.put(name, table);
    }
    return table;
}

private void addTable(String name)
{
    Table table = (Table)tableMap.get(name);
    if(table == null)
    {
        table = new Table(new File(databaseDirectory, name), charsetName);
        tableMap.put(name, table);
    }
}

public void removeTable(String name)
{
    tableMap.remove(name);
}

public void removeTable(Table table)
{
    tableMap.remove(table.getName());
}

public String getCharsetName()
{
    return charsetName;
}

private final File databaseDirectory;
private final Map tableMap;
private final Version version;
private final String charsetName;
}
```

Comment: Your LogCat shows the error is in `Database.java` post this class.

Comment: Meh. Was afraid of that. Database.java is in an imported library. Does that mean the library is broken?>.<

Comment: Could be, but more likely you are using it properly. What is line 43 above? `(at com.example.bosbouwapp.screen1$2.onClick(screen1.java:43)`)

Comment: Database databaseNieuw = new Database(new File(naamDatabase), Version.DBASE_4)

Creating a new database file.

Comment: Sorry, you already said that, my brain was somewhere else. Anyway I found the documentation online and they use: `Database database = new Database(new File("newdatabase"), Version.DBASE_3);` which aside from the version is identical to what you have...

Comment: Yeah, have a look at Database.class above.

Comment: Highlight/identify lines 112 and 64?

Comment: Will do, give me a moment.

Comment: Also - step through the code with the IDE debugger - check object status of all relevant objects before the call that fails is made.

Comment: The class only has 98 lines so I can't highlight line 112. Line 64 is the following line:    
    
     }  <-- 64
which is above
     return table;

Comment: If you have the source files included (as you do) you can step into these calls and see where the issue occurs... I suspect it should be pretty easy to track down.

Comment: Myeah that's what I'm trying to do but I'm not really getting anything out of it as the error lays on a line which doesn't declare a variable.

Comment: If you are stepping through the code you can see where it actually throws the error as opposed to what appears to be an incorrect line number...

Comment: One more thought: can you verify permissions to the directory on the dev environment - I suspect your issue may lie there.

Answer (score 1):

Can you put a break point in your code and step through it to see if you are trying to make a call at any point on a non-initialized object, or are passing a null object to the Database class? Specifically confirm that `naamDatabase` is not null when you pass it on line 43? Also is this string what you expect it to be at the point the call is made?

**UPDATE**

as I note in the comment, when stepping through what is the state of the file object below:

```
File file = new File(naamDatabase);
```

Breakpoint here - check file object is not null

```
Database databaseNieuw = new Database(file, Version.DBASE_4);
```

Comment: I've tried replacing 'naamDatabase' with actual text. Didn't change a thing. The error is on the actual line that creates the database.

Comment: Is this the version of the library you are using? ( http://dans-dbf-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/nl/knaw/dans/common/dbflib/Database.html ) Can you create your file object in advance and ensure it returns a valid result? If you got a permission error on creating the file perhaps it returns null? Will post code above:

Comment: That's the version I'm using, yes. Very good suggestion. The file object was successfully created and the error remains on the database line:/

Answer (score 0):

The error here is in the Database class, and without seeing that it's not possible to trace the problem. If you're sure that everything you're passing into Database is not null, then it's the Database class that is to blame.

I'd suggest getting in touch with whoever created that Database class, whatever it does!

Comment: Right, thanks. I'm not going to paste the Database.class from Dans dbf library here as it's rather large. Ill see if I can find a solution. It's good to know it's not me!

Comment: I'd rather it was me! At least you don't have to find/fix bugs in other peoples code that you thought was working :-(

Comment: Myeah, I was hoping that too since that'd be easier to fix:P Thanks for answering!